# Replace character in a string using awk or sed

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

Given the string below, how can I replace 6th and 7th by getting 14th and 15th digit using awk or sed.

```
xxxxx02xxxxxx89xx
xxxxx22xxxxxx33xx
```

output

```
xxxxx89xxxxxx89xx
xxxxx33xxxxxx33xx
```

I am newbie here, sorry for my question.

Answer (score 3):

The sed command is straightforward, but hard to read:

```
sed 's/\(.....\)..\(......\)\(..\)/\1\3\2\3/'
```

A possibly more maintainable solution can be had with Gnu `awk` (but not other awk varieties. However, see below.):

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 2 6 2 999" -v OFS='' '{$2=$4;print}'
```

The `FIELDWIDTHS` variable defines 5 fixed-width fields: the first 5 characters, the next two characters (positions 6 and 7); the next six characters (8 through 13); the next two characters (14 and 15); and the next (up to) 999 characters, which should be the rest of the line. (If you have longer lines, increase as necessary). Setting `OFS` to empty is often useful with fixed-length fields; it prevents `awk` from inserting spaces between fields in the output.

`FIELDWIDTHS` is a GNU awk extension. However, it is easy enough to reimplement in Posix `awk`. Here's a simple implementation:

```
function fieldwidth_set(         i) {
  if (PROCINFO["FS"]) FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS;
  else if (length(FIELDWIDTHS)) {
    _FW_NF = split(FIELDWIDTHS, _FW_ARRAY);
    for (i in _FW_ARRAY) {
      if (_FW_ARRAY[i] !~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
        printf "Illegal value '%s' in FIELDWIDTHS\n", _FW_ARRAY[i] >>"/dev/stderr";
        exit 1;
      }
      _FW_ARRAY[i]+=0;
    }
  } else
    _FW_NF = 0;
}
function set_fieldwidth(fw) { FIELDWIDTHS=fw; fieldwidth_set(); }
function fw_(               a,i,k) {
  if (_FW_NF) {
    a = $0;
    $0 = "";
    k=1;
    for (i=1; i<=_FW_NF; ++i) { 
      $i = substr(a, k, _FW_ARRAY[i]);
      k+=_FW_ARRAY[i];
    }
  }
}
BEGIN{set_fieldwidth()}
{fw_()}
```

As far as I know, only Gnu awk lets you mix program files and program text on the `awk` command-line. Posix requires the `-f program-file` option, which may be repeated, but does not require the `-e program-text` option as implemented by Gnu awk. Consequently, if you want to use the above snippet with a command-line awk program, you need to do something like this:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 2 6 2 999" -v OFS= -f fw.awk -f <(echo '{$2=$4;print}')
```

(Assuming you put the fieldwidth snippet into `fw.awk`.)

For efficiency, `fw.awk` insists that you tell it that you've changed `FIELDWIDTHS` by calling `fieldwidth_set()`. Or you can use `set_fieldwidth("....")` to set `FIELDWIDTHS` to a new value. It will work with GNU awk as well as with other awk implementations; it lets GNU awk do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Why do you do `($2=$4)||1` instead of `{$2=$4}1`?

Comment: @jotne: Why not? No good reason, although I have a vague and quite possibly incorrect feeling that it produces slightly better intermediate code.

Comment: I just asked to know if one is better, faster, more robust than the other, have not seen it done this way. I know for sure just using `'$2=$4'` will fail if input is `0`

Comment: A few years ago we had a fairly lengthy discussion among the regulars at comp.lang.awk about constructs like `($2=$4)||1` and the consensus was that it just obfuscates the code since it's putting an action (the assignment) into the condition part but then adding a second condition (`||1`) to force awk to ignore the result of the assignment and has no benefit vs `{$2=$4}1`.

Comment: @edmorton: Fair enough. But the unobfuscated version is presumably `{$2=$4;print}`. I'll change it in a bit.

Comment: The benefit of using `1` outweighs the extra clarity of `print` in a small script because it drives home multiple awk fundamentals simultaneously: 1) that an awk script is make of `<condition>{<action>}` statements, and 2) that the default `<action>` is to print the current record. Everyone NEEDS to know both of those to use awk effectively so either they already do and the meaning of `1` is obvious or they don't and having to learn what `1` does teaches them.

Comment: @EdMorton: What exactly is the benefit of `{$2=$4}1`? That it saves five characters is only a benefit for golfers. `mawk`, which doesn't have a great optimizer but does provide a mechanism to dump virtual ops, shows that `{$2=$4;print}` to be the shortest compiled program, so it is presumably the fastest (and `($2=$4)||1` is the longest, so I stand corrected).

Comment: No, the benefit is neither brevity nor performance, it's precisely the learning opportunities that I described in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo 'xxxxx03xxxxxx75xx' | sed -r 's/^(.{5})(..)(.{6})../\1\2\3\2/g' 
xxxxx03xxxxxx03xx
$ echo 'xxxxx03xxxxxx75xx' | sed  's/^\(.\{5\}\)\(..\)\(.\{6\}\)../\1\2\3\2/g'
xxxxx03xxxxxx03xx
```

It replaces 14th and 15th digits with the digits in the position 6 and 7th.

```
$ echo 'xxxxx03xxxxxx75xx' | sed -r 's/^(.{5})..(.{6})(..)/\1\3\2\3/g'
xxxxx75xxxxxx75xx
$ echo 'xxxxx03xxxxxx75xx' | sed 's/^\(.\{5\}\)..\(.\{6\}\)\(..\)/\1\3\2\3/g'
xxxxx75xxxxxx75xx
```

It replaces 6th and 7th digits with the digits in the position 14th and 15th.

Comment: how if I would do the procedure with more than one record in a file?

Comment: sed processes every line in the input file

Comment: if there are more than two `02` on the same line then you must use the global flag for to replace both `02`'s with 89. sed and awk process the input line by line.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you, what I mean is if I have these files:file1: xxxxx03xxxxxx75xx file2: xxxxx25xxxxxx12xx file3: xxxxx11xxxxxx00xx, how can I change the 14th and 15th digit by getting 6th and 7th digit?

Comment: Hi, is it possible in sed?

Comment: yes, you could do this by running this sed command on every file separately,  `sed -r 's/^(.{5})(..)(.{6})../\1\2\3\2/g' file`

Comment: I do not see how your solution change the digi in position 6 and 7 with the one in position 14 and 15. `how can I replace 6th and 7th by getting 14th and 15th digit using awk or sed.`

Comment: Your can remove the stuff that does not answer OPs request.

Comment: It gives me this error. sed: illegal option -- r
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

Comment: your sed not support `-r` parameter. So try `sed 's/^\(.\{5\}\)..\(.\{6\}\)\(..\)/\1\3\2\3/g' file`

Comment: It works, thanks! How about if I want to replace 14th and 15th digit by 6th and 7th digit?

Answer (score 2):

This should follow your request and work with all `awk`:

```
awk '{$6=$14;$7=$15}1' FS= OFS= file
xxxxx89xxxxxx89xx
xxxxx33xxxxxx33xx
```

It will change the digit in position `6` by the one in `14` and the one in `7` with the one int `15`

If `FS=""` does not work, try this:

```
awk '{n=split($0,a,"");a[6]=a[14];a[7]=a[15];for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s",a[i];print ""}' input
```

---

As request in one of the comment:
`It works, thanks! How about if I want to replace 14th and 15th digit by 6th and 7th digit? –  Vision111`

```
awk '{$14=$6;$15=$7}1' FS= OFS= file
```

Comment: When I tried it: awk '{$6=$14;$7=$15}1' FS= OFS= sample: output:
xxxxx27xxxxxx89xx
xxxxx76xxxxxx72xx. Nothing changes

Comment: @Vision111  Its important that there are a space after `OFS=` in first example, or you can use `FS="" OFS=""`. Try this then `echo "xxxxx27xxxxxx89xx" | awk '{$6=$14;$7=$15}1' FS= OFS=`.  You can also try this `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=""} {$6=$14;$7=$15}1'` or this: `awk -v FS="" -v OFS="" '{$6=$14;$7=$15}1'`

Comment: I tried all the code you've provided but it didn't change the output. echo "xxxxx27xxxxxx89xx" | awk '{$6=$14;$7=$15}1' FS= OFS=
xxxxx27xxxxxx89xx

Comment: You have one space after the fine `=`.  From this `echo "xxxxx27xxxxxx89xx" | awk '{$6=$14;$7=$15}1' FS= OFS= `, I get: `xxxxx89xxxxxx89xx`.  This is plain `awk` and should work on most system.

Comment: @Jidder Why? I do see nothing special with this that make it `gawk`

Comment: @Jotne Setting FS and OFS to nothing does not work the same way when not in GAWK. Try running it with standard UNIX awk or using `--compat`.

Comment: @Jidder I dod not know.  Can you point me to some written information about this?

Comment: @Vision111  I have recreated my original post since there seems to be a difference in how setting `FS` to nothing works with different version of `awk`.  What OS are you on?

Comment: @EdMorton This will not work when Running with `--posix` though ?

Comment: @Jidder - I stand corrected, setting `FS=` IS a gawk extension. I had no idea... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work without GNU awk `GAWK`

```
awk 'sub(/[0-9]+/,substr($0,14,2))' file
```

Or longer but more generic

```
awk '{print substr($0,0,5) substr($0,14,2) substr($0,8)}' file
```

RESULT:

```
xxxxx89xxxxxx89xx
xxxxx33xxxxxx33xx
```

Comment: the first character position in a string is 1, not 0. If the 1st character was at position 0 then the 14th character would be at position 13, not 14. Your first substr() should be substr($0,1,5). I wouldn't use the sub() since there's nothing to suggest there can't be a digit in the first 5 characters or after the 7th one.

Comment: You can use 0 or 1, it makes no difference. And I know that's why I added the second solution.

Comment: Thats like saying you can use -157 or 1. Sure you'll get the substring starting at 1 but that's because that's what substr() produces given a subscript that's out of range, not because it's a valid subscript to use. All it does its obfuscate your code. Imagine you need to print the 1st char and then the 2nd char separately - writing `substr($0,0,1); substr($0,2,1)` would make no sense just like using the index 0 for the 1st char but 14 for the 14th char doesn't here.

Comment: Fair enough, i'll use `1` in the future then :)