# split a large string into substrings

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have this file:

```
>first
GTGAAGTGCGGCACCCCGTAGGTCAGACAAGGCGGTCACGCCGCATCCGACATCCAACGCCCGAGCCGGTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACC
>second
CGGTAAT
```

My expected output is this:

```
>first
GTGAAGTGCGGCACCCCGTAGGTCAGACAAGGCGGTCACGCCGCATCCGACATCCAACGC
CCCGAGCCGGTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACC
>second
CGGTAAT
```

Explanation: If (the line starts with '>') print; else if length of the string is greater than 60, split the string in substrings of 60.

My idea is something like this in awk, but also bash solutions are welcome:

```
gawk '/^>/ {print;next;} {len=length; if(len>60){DO SOMETHING HERE (LOOP?)} else {print}}'
```

Any help will be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Will `>` lines ever be longer than 60 characters?

Comment: > lines should be the same as in the input file (no matter the length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this `awk`?

```
awk -v FS= 
    '{for (i=0;i<=NF/60;i++) {
          for (j=1;j<=60;j++)
               printf "%s", $(i*60 +j)
          print ""
          }
     }' file
```

See output:

```
$ awk -v FS= '{for (i=0;i<=NF/60;i++) {for (j=1;j<=60;j++) printf "%s", $(i*60 +j); print ""}}' file
>first
GTGAAGTGCGGCACCCCGTAGGTCAGACAAGGCGGTCACGCCGCATCCGACATCCAACGC
CCGAGCCGGTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAACC
>second
CGGTAAT
```

You can make explicit the `>` condition with:

```
awk -v FS= '/^>/ {print; next} {for (i=0;i<=NF/60;i++) {for (j=1;j<=60;j++) printf "%s", $(i*60 +j); print ""}}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-v FS=` set field separator to nothing, so that every single character will be a field.
- `'/^>/ {print; next}` if the line starts with `>`, print it and go to the next line.
- `{for (i=0;i<=NF/60;i++) {for (j=1;j<=60;j++) printf "%s", $(i*60 +j); print ""}}` on the rest of the cases, loop in blocks of 60 characters, printing all of them and then a new line, until the end of line is reached.

Comment: This needs `gnu awk` do to the `FS=` (nothing)

Comment: @Jotne does it? Would it if `-v FS=""`? I don't have any not-gnu awk here.

Comment: I do not think so.  Try to use `--postix`.  If it still work, it should be OK. I did have a post some days ago, and due to comment from EdMorton and other I discovered that setting `FS` to nothing is a `gnu` implementation.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599654/replace-character-in-a-string-using-awk-or-sed/25600115#25600115 `I stand corrected, setting FS= IS a gawk extension. I had no idea... Thanks. –  Ed Morton`

Comment: Interesting, @Jotne, many thanks. We have to investigate what is the best workaround for this :)

Comment: @fedorqui Best work around is to avoid it all together if you want to make your script POSIX compliant as the behavior of the `awk` interpreter when the field separator is set to an empty string is undefined. Look at the 4th feature compare across various `awk`'s [here](http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison). You can play around with `split` using RE as `//` if you'd like for a work around.

Answer (score 5):

You can use built in `fold` utility in a BASH loop:

```
while read -r f; do
    [[ "$f" == '>'* ]] && echo "$f" || echo "$f" | fold -w 60
done < file
```

Comment: I did not know about "fold" command, and really works nice. Thanks for trying this :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
$ awk '!/^>/&&length($0)%60{gsub(/.{60}/,"&\n")}1' file
>first
GTGAAGTGCGGCACCCCGTAGGTCAGACAAGGCGGTCACGCCGCATCCGACATCCAACGC
CCGAGCCGGTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAACC
>second
CGGTAAT
```

**Note:** If you are using GNU `awk` v3.x then add `--re-interval` (`awk --re-interval '..' file`). For GNU `awk` v4 or later as well as BSD `awk` it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the splitting of the lines entirely and just do the substring printing manually.

```
awk -v FS='\n' '!/^>/ {for (i=0; i<(length($0)/60); i++) {print substr($0, i*60, 60)}; next}7'
```